# How to comment multi-line commands in shell scripts?

Tags: shell

When invoking long, switch-heavy commands, it's a good practice to write them in shell scripts. Is there an easy way to comment lines in such scripts? I've tried the following methods, but neither works.

```
# the \ is also commented out, resulting in "command" and "--good-switch".
command \
  #--bad-switch \
  --good-switch \

# seems to send an extra argument to the command
command \
  \ #--bad-switch \
  --good-switch
```

Comment: The second one causes a space to be sent as an argument (`\ ` escapes the next character, which "hides" newlines but makes spaces significant).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This might be an option: store the command and args in an array, then execute it after

```
# build the command
cmd=( ls
        -F
      # -a   # comment out this option temporarily
        -l
    )
# $cmd is now an array with 3 elements

# execute it
"${cmd[@]}"
```

Comment: This is `bash`-only…

Comment: @Socob, that syntax is from `zsh` and is also supported by ksh93, bash, yash and mksh.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Yes, sorry, that was slightly imprecise. What I meant was that it’s not POSIX shell-compatible (and the question is tagged [tag:shell]), and limited to `bash` or (to some degree) “`bash`-compatible” shells.

Answer (score 4):

I always moved the commented ones just after the command.

```
command \
  --good-switch
# --bad-switch          with explanation here, if needed
```

Answer (score 2):

See the [answer by Digital Ross](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455988/commenting-in-bash-script/1456019#1456019).

See also the question I just posted, [bash multi line command with comments after the continuation character](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19124/bash-multi-line-command-with-comments-after-the-continuation-character).

This would be a useful feature. It is a pity it does not have standard support.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind losing the value of the positional parameters, you can use them to build the command gradually. This also lets you use conditionals.

```
set -- command --first-option
# We need a special option on Tuesdays
if [ "$(date +%u)" = 2 ]; then
  set -- "$@" --tuesday
fi
set -- "$@" --last-option
# Finally we execute the command
"$@"
```

If you want to add options before the positional parameters, you might need to build the command backwards.

```
# We have a list of files in the positional parameters.
set -- --last-option "$@"
# We need a special option on Tuesdays
if [ "$(date +%u)" = 2 ]; then
  set -- --tuesday "$@"
fi
set -- command --first-option "$@"
# Finally we execute the command
"$@"
```

If you need to preserve the positional parameters, put this code in a function: the positional parameters are restored when the function returns.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the slashes are removed before the line is parsed, so the first command is parsed as if you'd written `command   #--bad-switch   --good-switch`. If you have a really long sequence of commands, you could for example write a **line-by-line comment block** above or below it, explaining each in turn, or you could store the parameters in a variable (although that often gives quoting headaches with special characters).

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the case. `--good-switch` is interpreted as a command.

Answer (score 1):

a comment brakes the chain of conected lines, so the simplest solution would be to move the commented lines at the end of the list.

```
command \
  --good-switch \
  # --bad-switch \
```

If you don't want to change the order, you can use the `:` command (the colon utility, which does nothing) to keep the connected lines intact:

```
command \
  `: --bad-switch `\
  --good-switch \
```

---

I tested with this:

```
function command { 
  echo "num args:" $#;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ echo abc `# comment` \
>      def `# comment 2` \
>      ghi
abc def ghi

$ echo abc `# comment` \
>      `#def # comment entire line` \
>      ghi
abc ghi
```

The backticks perform [Command Substituion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html). This works because there is no standard output from executing a comment.

Comment: This spaws a new shell for every comment. What a waste of cycles for something basic as a comment. Too bad there is no simple built-in way.