# How to insert inline comment in multiline command?

Tags: bash, command

I'd like to do this on bash

```
apt install -y \
   curl \  # i'd like to insert comment here somehow
   python3
```

But this doesn't work.

Comment: Similar: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/19124/117549

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One approach:

```
apt install -y \
   curl `# my comment` \
   python3
```